# Issue with certain websites

Tags: networking, wireless, intel-wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and home WiFi. There are certain websites that cannot be accessed, e.g. udacity.com, under Chrome and Firefox both with latest version. And I have dual OS, it works properly on Win10. It works on other WiFi under Ubuntu. So the problem is restricted within home WiFi, but it works on smartphone.

Here is a MTR report under Ubuntu for `mtr --report udacity.com`

```
Start: Wed Jun  8 12:27:58 2016
HOST: Lenovo Laptop   Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- 193.197.62.222            90.0%    10   17.6  17.6  17.6  17.6   0.0
  2.|-- 132.230.121.18             0.0%    10   16.9  16.4  14.8  18.8   1.1
  3.|-- Karlsruhe-RZ-1-bundle-eth  0.0%    10   19.9  20.6  17.7  29.5   3.3
  4.|-- Stuttgart-NWZ-1-10GE-0-4-  0.0%    10   21.2  19.3  18.2  21.2   0.7
  5.|-- sgrt-b1-link.telia.net     0.0%    10   21.3  21.6  19.5  30.5   3.1
  6.|-- ffm-bb3-link.telia.net     0.0%    10   22.4  23.6  22.4  24.9   0.7
  7.|-- nyk-bb2-link.telia.net     0.0%    10  118.5 126.2 117.7 176.3  18.1
  8.|-- nyk-b3-link.telia.net      0.0%    10  117.1 119.2 116.8 121.3   1.5
  9.|-- netaccess-tic-133837-nyk-  0.0%    10  119.0 112.4 107.0 120.1   4.9
 10.|-- 0.e1-4.tbr1.mmu.nac.net    0.0%    10  109.7 112.5 108.4 120.8   4.1
 11.|-- 207.99.109.70              0.0%    10  107.8 109.9 107.8 112.4   1.1
 12.|-- 173.255.239.3              0.0%    10  109.9 111.5 108.9 121.1   3.5
 13.|-- ???                       100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Other sites such as askubuntu.com is no problem, so its report also provided `mtr --report askubuntu.com`

```
  1.|-- 193.197.62.222            90.0%    10   15.3  15.3  15.3  15.3   0.0
  2.|-- 132.230.121.18             0.0%    10   16.7  21.5  14.9  57.4  13.0
  3.|-- Karlsruhe-RZ-1-bundle-eth  0.0%    10   17.5  20.1  17.5  29.3   3.4
  4.|-- Stuttgart-NWZ-1-10GE-0-4-  0.0%    10   18.3  19.8  18.3  22.0   0.8
  5.|-- sgrt-b1-link.telia.net     0.0%    10   21.5  20.3  18.2  26.9   2.5
  6.|-- ffm-bb3-link.telia.net     0.0%    10   24.5  23.7  21.9  25.4   1.0
  7.|-- ffm-b1-link.telia.net      0.0%    10   23.4  23.8  21.9  30.2   2.3
  8.|-- ???                       100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  9.|-- 151.101.193.69             0.0%    10   22.1  22.9  20.8  32.7   3.4
```

And for Google, `mtr --report google.com`

```
  1.|-- 2a02:8071:b283:b500:4632:  0.0%    10    1.5   1.2   1.0   1.5   0.0
  2.|-- ???                       100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  3.|-- 2a02:8071:b0ff:30a3::1     0.0%    10    9.8   9.4   8.3  11.1   0.7
  4.|-- de-kae01a-rd1.kae.unity-m  0.0%    10   13.3  14.7  12.7  18.1   1.6
  5.|-- de-fra04a-ri1-ae14.fra.un  0.0%    10   14.3  14.3  13.1  15.6   0.6
  6.|-- 2001:730:2d00::5474:8066   0.0%    10   41.2  26.1  12.5  45.2  13.8
  7.|-- 2001:730:2d00::5474:8001   0.0%    10   14.0  15.0  13.5  17.7   1.2
  8.|-- 2001:730:2d02:13::d52e:b3  0.0%    10   14.2  14.8  13.6  17.2   0.9
  9.|-- 2001:4860::1:0:abf0        0.0%    10   15.3  15.1  13.9  16.4   0.6
 10.|-- 2001:4860::4:0:2668        0.0%    10   20.3  21.9  20.1  30.5   3.1
 11.|-- 2001:4860:0:1::3b1         0.0%    10   20.4  23.8  19.3  40.0   6.2
 12.|-- zrh04s05-in-x0e.1e100.net  0.0%    10   19.4  19.5  18.4  22.0   0.9
```

It seems the problem is because the udacity.com cannot reach the final destination, since it indicates "???" on hop number 13. How this issue could probably solved ?

Comment: I had similar problems on my home wifi network (with several different ubuntu pc) and solved it by editing wifi connection on every pc and change MTU value to 1480 from automatic (which means 1500). Strange thing that i can access `udacity.com` but when i try `ping udacity.com` I get 100% package loss...

Comment: @ThanosApostolou Thanks for comment. I would like to know if you can explorer udacity.com, by clicking more pages, e.g. sign in, catalog  ?  Because sometimes I could access homepage on private browsing, but after clicking anything on the homepage, it fails again.

Comment: @ThanosApostolou I've tried to change MTU of the WiFi connection to 1480, but problem remains

Comment: All pages seem to work fine on me http://imgur.com/CqnKVbQ. You restarted wifi after changing MTU right? If not try `sudo service network-manager restart`. Try also setting 1478 MTU maybe works better.

Comment: @ThanosApostolou Yes, it is changed as it can be shown with ifconfig. So it is very strange to me why it happens.

Comment: Strange indeed. I can't help you more, my `mtr --report udacity.com` output is this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/17114171/

Comment: @ThanosApostolou Amazing ! I tried to change MTU to 1460, it works now. Thank you so much for the solution !

Comment: @ThanosApostolou I've tried lots of methods in last weeks, this one works. I think you can post this as an Answer and I shall accept it as an answer so that it might help other people with same issue in the future time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,well, the problem is that default MTU value is problematic at some networks (MTU is set to automatic which means 1500 for wifi). I had similar problems (with hotmail.com) so I solved them by changing MTU at value 1480. @Xingdong solved his by changing MTU to 1460 (as discussed at comments).
Easiest way to change MTU value is clicking on wifi icon and select `Edit Connections`. Then select your wifi connection and click `Edit`. Under `Wi-Fi` tab change MTU from `automatic` to a value that works for you (search web for some usually used MTU values depending on your internet connection). Then disable and re enable wifi for change to take effect. MTU must be 1500 or lower for wifi and ethernet and as close to 1500 as possible. The only method that worked for me in order to find correct MTU value is to start from 1498 and decreasing by 2 each time until the desired sites work.